Elstrodt: Maß- und Integrationstheorie: Exercise II.1.6d
I am working through exercise II.1.6 from Elstrodt and there is one part (part d) of the exercise that I don't understand. The exercise has several parts, so I will just state the parts that I have already solved.

Exercise 1.6 (English translation): Let $\mu$ be a content on the ring
$\mathfrak{R}$ over $X$. Show that:
a) $A \sim B : \iff \mu(A \Delta B) = 0 \quad (A,B \in \mathfrak{R})$
is an equivalence relation on $\mathfrak{R}$.
b) The equivalence class $\mathfrak{N} := \{A \in \mathfrak{R}: A \sim \emptyset\}$ of the empty set contains exactly the $\mu$-null sets and
$\mathfrak{N}$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{R}$.
c) For all $A,B \in \mathfrak{R}$ with $A \sim B$, $\mu(A) = \mu(B) = \mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A \cup B)$.
d) Now let $\mu$ be finite and $\delta: \mathfrak{R} \times \mathfrak{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \delta(A,B) := \mu(A \Delta B)$ for $A,B \in \mathfrak{R}$. Show that $\delta$ is a pseudo-metric. Also show that $|\mu(A) - \mu(B)| \leq \delta(A,B) \quad (A,B \in \mathfrak{R})$, and thus $\mu$ is uniformly continuous w.r.t to $\delta$. Furthermore, the set operations $\cap, \cup, \setminus,\Delta$ are uniformly continuous functions from $\mathfrak{R} \times \mathfrak{R} \to \mathfrak{R}$ w.r.t $\delta$.

The bold part is where I am stuck since the exercise does not even specify any metric on $\mathfrak{R} \times \mathfrak{R}$. Is there a natural metric to use (based on $\delta$)? I feel like I am missing some information to solve the last part of d).
Thanks for any help and suggestions!
Edit: I have just realized that it does not even matter what metric we use for $\mathfrak{R} \times \mathfrak{R}$. For example, for $\cap$  we have
\begin{align*}
\delta(A_1 \cap B_1,A_2 \cap B_2) & = \mu((A_1 \cap B_1) \Delta (A_2 \cap B_2)) \\
  & = \mu((A_1 \cap B_1) \setminus (A_2 \cap B_2)) + \mu((A_2 \cap B_2) \setminus (A_1 \cap B_1))
\end{align*}
and since $\mu$ is finite we can use the subtraction property to show that the right-hand side is $0$. So $\cap$ is uniformly continuous no matter what metric we choose for $\mathfrak{R} \times \mathfrak{R}$.
A similar argument works for $\cup, \setminus$ and $\Delta$.
Does that make sense?

Since the previous questions involve an equivalence relation, I believe the author wants you to work with the quotient space $X/\sim = \{[x] | x\in X\}$.
A pseudo-metric $d$ on $X$ defines an equivalence relation $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow d(x,y)=0$. Then $\delta\colon X/\sim\to [0,\infty)$ with $\delta([x],[y]) := d(x,y)$ is well-defined and a metric on $X/\sim$. A metric induces a so called diagonal uniformity $\mathcal D\subseteq \mathcal P(X\times X)$, which satisfies:

$\forall D\in\mathcal D: \Delta\subseteq D$, where $\Delta = \{(x,x)|x\in X\}$,
$\forall D\in\mathcal D: \exists E\in\mathcal D: E\circ E\subseteq D$, where $E\circ E := \{(x,z)\in X\times X: \exists y\in X: (x,y),(y,z)\in E\}$,
$\forall D\in\mathcal D: \exists E\in\mathcal D: E^{-1}\subseteq D$, where $E^{-1} = \{(y,x) | (x,y)\in E\}$,
$\forall D,E\in\mathcal D: D\cap E\in\mathcal D$,
$\forall D\in \mathcal D: D\subseteq E\implies E\in\mathcal D$.

Note that $\mathcal D$ is a filter with respect to set-inclusion. A metric $\delta$ then induces a filterbase
$$
\mathcal E := \{D_\varepsilon >0\} \qquad D_\varepsilon = \{(x,y)\in X\times X: \delta(x,y) <\varepsilon\}
$$
which generates a diagonal uniformity $\mathcal D_\delta$.
If $\mathcal D$ is a diagonal uniformity on $X$, we call $(X,\mathcal D)$ a uniform space. Given uniform spaces $(X,\mathcal D_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal D_Y)$, we call a map $f\colon X\to Y$ uniformly continuous, if $\forall V\in\mathcal D_Y: \{(x_1,x_2)| (f(x_1),f(x_2))\in U\}\in\mathcal D_X$.
It remains to find a diagonal uniformity on $X\times X$. To achieve this, we consider $(X/\sim)^2$ instead. Then we can work with the product metric, which is the unique metric that generates the product topology. I believe, for finite cartesian products, you can simple use
$$
\delta_\Pi((x,y),(a,b)) := \max(\delta(x,y),\delta(a,b))
$$
to get a topological space equivalent to the product space. Given the product metric, you can construct a diagonal uniformity on $X\times X$ analogous to the one on $X$ and thus verify $\cap$,$\cup$,$\setminus$ and the symmetric difference are in fact uniformly continuous.
I'd suggest reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric

Edit: I maybe should have searched on how to get a uniform structure on the cartesian product. Given a uniform space $(X,\mathcal D)$, the filterbase
$$
\{D\times C | D,C\in \mathcal D\}
$$
generates a diagonal uniformity on $X\times X$. Furthermore, in order to avoid working with the quotient space $X/\sim$,
$$
\{\{y\in X: d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}| x\in X,\varepsilon >0\}
$$
is already a filterbase for a diagonal uniformity on $X$.

Thanks for your long answer, but I don't think the author expects the readers to know all of this when it is not even mentioned anywhere in the exercise. However, the hint about the product topology is a good one. When I first looked at the exercise some time ago I also thought that the author probably implicitly assumes that $\mathfrak{R} \times \mathfrak{R}$ should be endowed with a metric that generated the product topology.
